# Do you need a separate graphics pipeline for each multiview render pass?

Tags: vulkan

Let's just say I have different versions of render passes depending on how many views/layers I want to render to, let's say 1 (for normal single-plane rendering), 2 (for VR), and 6 for cubemaps. So for each render pass type I might have these three sub-types. Each sub-type has this information given to create the render pass:

```
typedef struct VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo {
    VkStructureType    sType;
    const void*        pNext;
    uint32_t           subpassCount;
    const uint32_t*    pViewMasks;
    uint32_t           dependencyCount;
    const int32_t*     pViewOffsets;
    uint32_t           correlationMaskCount;
    const uint32_t*    pCorrelationMasks;
} VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo;
```

My question is, when we create a graphics pipeline you have to give a sub-pass. Does filling the above struct with different information result in the sub-passes in the render pass created not compatible with each other? And so necessitating the creation of separate graphics pipeline objects for each of the multiview types?

Comment: What kind of shader would you write that would be *the same* for rendering to multi-view and single-view render targets (let alone cubemap rendering)? The fragment shaders may be the same, but all the vertex processing wouldn't. This question doesn't seem to serve a purpose.

Comment: @NicolBolas All of them! For all shaders you bind (somewhere/anywhere) a uniform buffer/storage buffer containing an array of camera view matrices. For VR stereoscopic you have two camera matrices, and index into each of them depending on the gl_ViewIndex. Same as for cubemap except the framebuffer image attachments have 6 layers, and you attach an array of 6 camera view matrices in the shading descriptor binding and just index into it with gl_ViewIndex. If this can be done the way I think it can, it's awesome.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why do you say the vertex processing would be different? Am I missing something? To do this without multiview manually you'd render 2/6 times, why would you change the shaders/pipeline each time when rendering different views? I can understand needing to change the framebuffers, but the shaders/pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With certain very minor exceptions (view count [not being one of them](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap8.html#renderpass-compatibility)), if the render passes are different, then you must use a different pipeline.

It should also be noted that multiview and layered rendering use the same underlying resources. That is, multiview is a form of layered rendering. As such, if a render pass/pipeline expects multiview, it cannot use layered rendering for non-multiview purposes. That is, in multiview each layer you render to is considered a "view" for multiview purposes. Which means that it *automatically* routes primitives to specific layers based on the view mask (all rendering commands in a multi-view subpass are automatically repeated for multiple views, and you're [not allowed to write to `Layer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap10.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-renderPass-06049)). In layered rendering, it's up to the user code to which layer(s) a rendering command renders to)

Lastly, let us look at dynamic rendering in Vulkan 1.3 (aka: rendering without a render pass). With this feature, you don't have to build a render pass, and pipelines meant to be used for such rendering are not built against a render pass. However, this won't exactly fix your problem.

Even though you aren't building your pipelines against an entire `VkRenderPass` structure, you still need to give the pipeline some idea of what you're rendering to. This is provided by the `VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo` at pipeline creation time. Among other things, this struct specifies the `viewMask` for that subpass.

And this value [must exactly match the value you used with `vkCmdBeginRendering`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap20.html#VUID-vkCmdDraw-viewMask-06178). So you will need pipelines to be built against a specific multiview setup, and therefore, you will need separate pipelines for each multiview setup.

Single-view rendering should not be considered a special case of multi-view rendering. They are two different ways of rendering.

Comment: "Single-view rendering should not be considered a special case of multi-view rendering. They are two different ways of rendering." I read that it's disabled when the view mask is 0. Is this the best way to enable/disable it?

Comment: @Zebrafish: That's what enabled/disabled *means*. Particularly if you're using vkCreateRenderPass2.